# Copying Specific lines of a csv file

Tags: c

I have a csv file like this:

```
18, max, 13, 18
82, jim, 29, 23
29, holly, 3, 39
```

The first column is the "ID". I want to make a csv file in C that, given an integer command line argument, deletes the line with that integer ID. For example if I ran `./a.out 18`, I would want to delete the first line of this. If that number entered doesn't exist, then an error is shown.

Basically, I want to copy everything but that line into a new csv file, then delete the old csv, and rename the new csv the old csv file's name.

I am having a lot of trouble with this and I need help! Help much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages.  You should show what you've tried so far, and explain the difference between the results you are getting and the results you want.  Which of the steps are causing you problems?  What should happen if the ID appears multiple times in the input?

Comment: As with any problem *break it down into smaller pieces*. You need to (1) open the file for *reading* and a second file for *writing*; (2) read the file line-by-line; (3) separate the first comma-separated field for comparison; (4) compare the first field of the line to the command line argument; (5) if the field does not compare to the argument, write the line to the new file, (*Repeat until no more lines*) (6) delete original file (7) move new file to old file name, done...

Comment: I thought of that, but I just don't know how to write a specific line.

Comment: Also we're supposed to delete the FIRST record that matches the ID

Comment: Never mind I got it thanks so much guys